# How to wrap a element among dozen of element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Suppose using `.wrap()` can wrap a tag on **a** element, however I want to wrap a tag among **dozen of** element. How can I do that?

Thanks

BEFORE

```
<div class="jw_playlist_playlist">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

AFTER

```
<div class="jw_playlist_playlist">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wrapAll()`:

```
$('.jw_playlist_playlist li').wrapAll('<ul>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Or thinking about it from a different direction, use `wrapInner`

http://jsfiddle.net/z9Jah/

```
$('.jw_playlist_playlist').wrapInner('<ul />');​
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab each item, on the first LI, insert a  tag before it. on the last LI, insert a UL tag after it

```
var listItems = $(".jw_playlist_playlist li");
$.each(listItems, function(i,v){
  if(i==0){ 
    $(this).insertBefore('<ul>');
  }else if(i == listItems.length - 1){
   $(this).insertAfter('</ul>'); 
  }
});
```